# Increasing speed of React rendering for IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, jsx

I'm making a angular application which returns a list of objects that need to be rendered on the page (around 30 items).

For increasing render performance i use react components. the whole thing is written in typescript and a react components looks like the following:

```
namespace app {
    'use strict';
    export interface IServiceOrganicProps extends IOrganicResultProps {
        result: Service;
    }

    export class ServiceOrganic extends React.Component<IServiceOrganicProps, {}> {
        render(): any {
            return (
                <div className="service-organic flex">
                    <div className="layout-row">
                        <div className="icon">
                            <img src="img/service.ico"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex layout-column">
                            <div className="title" title={"score: " + this.props.result.score}><a href={this.props.result.url}>{this.props.result.name}</a></div>
                            <div className="link">{this.props.result.url}</div>
                            <p className="body">{ this.props.result.description }</p>
                            <div className="tags">
                                <ul>
                                    {this.props.result.tags.map(function (tag) {
                                        return <li key={tag}><a href="#">{tag}</a></li>;
                                    }) }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    angular.module("app").value("ServiceOrganic", ServiceOrganic);
    angular.module('app').directive('serviceOrganic', function (reactDirective: any, $log: angular.ILogService) {
        return reactDirective(ServiceOrganic, ['result'], {}, { $log: $log });
    });
}
```

this works great on chrome:

- load time: 1s
- rendering ~160ms
- painting: ~1.5ms

but on IE11 this is:

- load time +4s
- DOM event (load): ~1.7s
- Layout: ~750ms

Is there any way to increase the load time on IE?

Comment: I think the title of this question is a little misguided. It's not the syntax 'jsx' that's slow as jsx isn't interpreted by the browser, it's more accurately React that you're finding to be too slow.

Comment: @riscarrott: you are correct, I've updated the title

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html